# Stop Tkinter menu automatically running commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning python, and this week I got the basics of GUI coding.

The issue I am having is with **f1handler1()** at the bottom, please can you help me understand how is it possible to make the menu command wait until the associated menu item is clicked on first? as currently as soon as I perform secondary-mouse-click to bring up the menu, it automatically deletes the selected item before I made my menu choice :(
(yet for some reason the quit option doesn't?)

Many thanks.
(Apologies if the code is hard to read, it's my first language and GUI I'm picking up slowly from the course I'm doing and lots of web-searches.)

```
from tkinter import *

ALL = N+S+W+E

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        #initiate the primary window.
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=3)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.grid(sticky=ALL)
        self.frameset()

    def frameset(self):
        #define and setup frames with columns and rows for widgets
        #Colours added to framesets to help designing layout. delete them
        self.Frame1 = Frame(self, bg='blue')   # D
        self.Frame2 = Frame(self, bg='green')  # E
        self.Frame3 = Frame(self)              # L
        self.Frame4 = Frame(self, bg='green')  # E
        self.Frame5 = Frame(self, bg='orange') # T
        self.Frame6 = Frame(self, bg='yellow') # E colours

        self.Frame1.rowconfigure(0,weight=0)
        self.Frame2.rowconfigure(0,weight=0)
        self.Frame3.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.Frame4.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.Frame5.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.Frame6.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.Frame1.columnconfigure(0,weight=0)
        self.Frame2.columnconfigure(0,weight=0)
        self.Frame3.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.Frame4.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.Frame5.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.Frame6.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.Frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky=ALL)
        self.Frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=ALL)
        self.Frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky=ALL)
        self.Frame4.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=ALL)
        self.Frame5.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky=ALL)
        self.Frame6.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=ALL)


        label4a = Label(self.Frame4, text='Accounts', bg='orange')
        label4b = Label(self.Frame4, text='Recent Payroll', bg='yellow')
        label4a.pack(side=LEFT)
        label4b.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.objects()

    def objects(self):
        self.f3ListBox = Listbox(self.Frame3, selectmode='single')
        self.f3ListBox.insert(1,'Colchester 441')
        self.f3ListBox.insert(2,'Chelmsford 914')
        self.f3ListBox.insert(3,'London 123')
        self.f3ListBox.grid(sticky=ALL)
        self.f3ListBox.bind("<Button-3>", self.f1handler1)

        f5ListBox = Listbox(self.Frame5, selectmode='single')
        f5ListBox.insert(0,'Fred Asus')
        f5ListBox.insert(1,'Tom Yahoo')

        f5ListBox.grid(sticky=ALL)

        f6ListBox = Listbox(self.Frame6, selectmode='single')
        f6ListBox.insert(1,'S123456') # DELETE
        f6ListBox.grid(sticky=ALL)

        #Dropdown menu to use on the top left corner        
        var = StringVar()
        var.set('Costcode')
        dmenu1 = OptionMenu(self.Frame1,var, 'Costcode','Name')
        dmenu1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

    def f1handler1(self,event):
        """Creates a popup menu for the alternative mouse button.
        Edit this to add more options to that popup"""
        select = self.f3ListBox.delete(ACTIVE)
        popup = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        popup.add_command(label='Quit',command=self.quit)
        popup.add_command(label='delete',command=select) #add more of these for more options


        try:
            popup.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        except:
            pass


root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is actually before adding the command, where you have

```
select = self.f3ListBox.delete(ACTIVE)
```

As soon as this is executed, it performs the delete operation and assigns the result of it to `select`. You should do something like

```
select = lambda: self.f3ListBox.delete(ACTIVE)
```

to create a function that will call `delete` at the appropriate time. You can then pass `select` as the command for the menu item as you are doing.

Comment: Abe, thanks, this has worked a treat, I just need to go learn/understand lambda now :)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes when setting a button command in tkinter, the command is automatically called instead of waiting for a click. 
A possible solution may be to add in lambda

```
popup.add_command(label='Quit',command= lambda: self.quit)
```

Comment: What you say isn't quite correct. The command is never automatically called unless you specifically request it to be called. It's not a mysterious feature of Tkinter -- this only happens when you use Tkinter incorrectly. Plus, in your specific example, the lambda is totally useless.

Comment: NoxSatuKei : I tried your suggestion (I used it against the delete menu option) and it didn't make a difference I'm afraid. Abe Karplus provided a solution which works perfect. Thank you.